# Remote force logout in passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I want to make a "remote logout" feature in our website.

Some services provide this feature, like google..
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154

I use passport.js in node.js, so I want to find how can I make this feature but cannot find how to do it.

I want to destroy session by user's id.
We need to sign out all session of that user's, because people sign in by using many browsers and devices.

Comment: I have exactly same question. I think only way is remove session from database.

Comment: Any followup? Need this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I added a similar feature to this to my website.

I couldn't find a way to do it using PassportJS, but what I did was add and extra Boolean field to my users schema (mongoDB) called `FORCE_LOGOUT`.

I changed the value of `FORCE_LOGOUT` to `true` via a `POST` request from my front end.

Then in my main app.js script I checked to see if the user had that field as true and then forced them to logout if it was before allowing them to continue.

I use expressJs so it looked something like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user && req.user.FORCE_LOGOUT){
        req.user.FORCE_LOGOUT = false;
        req.user.save(err => {
            if(err) console.error(err);
            req.logout();
            return next();
        })
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

There is probably a much better way to achieve this, but this is how I worked around it, so hopefully it will help to guide somebody else.